# Bootstrap Popovers not working in Popup modals (not z-index)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I have created a popover to show users hints of what buttons are for etc, well, they work on my website but when I try to use one inside a popup modal it doesn't iniate.

**None popup modal:**

[image]

**Popup modal**

[image]

MY Javascript to iniate the popup modal:

```
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: "hover",  placement: 'auto left'});
```

To load my modals I am using `$.ajax()` (if that's any help) like so:

```
//$(document).off('click');
$(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $("#globalModal").modal("show");
    var target = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,


    }).done(function(data)
        {
            $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));

            $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
        }) ;

});
```

**How I am creating my popover tooltips:**

```
<i class="fa fa-building" data-toggle="popover" title="Hint:" data-content="Get Driving directions"></i>
```

How can I fix this? It works but just not inside modals?

Comment: Set the z-index of the popover

Comment: Show your HTML. Do your popover icons are loaded into modal on page load or after ajax call?

Comment: ).done(function(data)
        {
            $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have to call popover after you load your icons.

```
}).done(function(data) {
  $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));
  $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: "hover",  placement: 'auto left'});
});
```